# Form data not being received properly in Node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a submit form in my react.js front ned, where i use filepond, to get the files, i don't figured a good way to send the files, was to use form data, to send the files.

```
fileItems.forEach((item, i) => {
     console.log(typeof item.file)
     const json = JSON.stringify(item.file);
     const blob = new Blob([json], {
           type: 'application/json'
             });
     const data = new FormData();
     data.append("document", blob)
     fileObjects.push({
           name: item.file.name,
           data: data
           });
       });
    this.setState({fileObjects});
```

when I log the fileObjects I get this result

[image: here is the console.log output]

But when I log the output in my node.js backend the data is just an empty object.

```
   result: [ { name: 'Udklip.PNG', data: {} } ] }
 [ [ { name: 'Udklip.PNG', content: {} } ] ]
```

i have made a handler to send the request to my node.js backend like such:

```
onSubmitHandler = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  const contactRequest = {
      email: this.state.email,
      name: this.state.name,
      message: this.state.message,            
      result: this.state.fileObjects
  }


const form = axios.post('/api/form', contactRequest)
console.log(contactRequest)
console.log(form)
}
```

how can i make the POST request to my node.js backend, and parse the files properly?

Comment: can you please be clear about your file structure and nodes code, also I don't understand how are you receiving th post request in the node.js file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entry in MDN shows [how to add files objects to FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch)

A [FilePond file item](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/file/) has a `file` property which is the actual file.

```
var file = item.file;
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('document', file, file.name);
```

Now you can send the form data to Axios:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api/form',
  data: myFormData
});
```

Comment: But then Can i send both The, form the data, and the rest og the data inside an object? Or do i have to maje two separate requests?

Comment: I would consult Axios docs, one thing is for sure, you can't serialize/stringify File objects.

Comment: i tried this, but i still don't receive anything in my backend

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using multer. But, then I had to add them as middleware since it handles multipart/form-data. Without it, you can't work with form data in backend.

```
import multer from 'multer'

var multer_middleware= multer()    
router.post("/signup", multer_middleware, signup);
```

Without multer, you can't work with form data and I suggest to use multer, since it has good methods to handle files.